# how to disable remote login to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, remote-access

The title pretty much sums up my question.
I just want to find out how to disable remote login to my phpmyadmin.
I would rather only being able to log into phpmyadmin from localhost.

Answer (score 8):

Edit `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` with :

```
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from localhost
```

Answer (score 4):

**Preventing remote login doesn’t stop access to phpmyadmin** if you have not stopped it in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

To turn the access to phpmyadmin OFF in **ubuntu 14.04 with apache** web server, edit `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

Search for `<Directory /phpmyadmin>` or `<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>` if you set the Alias `/phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin` in the same file.

Add or Edit following lines:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

Restart **apache2** with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To turn the access to phpmyadmin ON temporarily, first find out your ip address. Search Google, what is my ip address.
Then edit vi `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` file.
Add this line to the above mentioned Directory tag:
`Allow from <your ip address>`

Restart the apache2 with sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

On Centos and RHEL, it is saved here: `/etc/httpd/conf.d`

Edit add directory and deny or allow.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
Require all granted
 Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

Search for Directory /phpmyadmin or Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin

insert Require local between Directory /directory